# Can websites access photos on device if Chrome has access?

Tags: security, chrome-for-android, permissions, photos

If the Google Chrome app on Android has access to media/files/photos, can any website access photos on the device since the permission is granted to chrome, or would the photo picker (before the ability to grant specific photos to certain apps) have to be enacted to browse then upload after the chrome app called it?

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, the files can only be accessed when the user chooses them explicitly. Otherwise, this is a big security issue that should have been covered by news outlets many years ago. Also, websites can only interact with [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) provided by the browser.